# How to simplify a ratio

Tags: simplifying-expressions, rule

I have a ration of the form $\frac{p^2}{(p^2+1)^2}$. I can simplify it using $p^2=p^2+1-1$, and to get $\frac{p^2}{(p^2+1)^2}=\frac{1}{p^2+1}-\frac{1}{(p^2+1)^2}$. How can I create the rule to do it automatically with Mathematica ?

Comment: Have a look at `Apart`.

Comment: Exactly what I need, cheers !

Comment: Try this: `(p^2/(p^2 + 1)^2 /. p -> Sqrt[q - 1] // Expand) /. q -> p^2 + 1`. Have fun!